# Does Preference Screen in android use recycler view?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a requirement of a preferences screen in android which has around 250 preferences. The activity is taking a time to load because it contains 250 items.

If preferences screen uses recycler view inside why does it try to render all the items (even which are not visible) at once ?

What am I missing ?

Comment: u have debug on it and onBindViewHolder jump on 250 times?

Comment: @shadow I tired only populating 10 items, it was fast, but good idea

Comment: i just wanna make sure it really load 250 items or maybe it load the item which not visiblle.if it really is,better provide the adapter @Ninja420